# Comparison of simple linear regression, stepwise, lasso, and ridge

Tags: regression, prediction, model-selection, lasso, model-evaluation

I am a totally beginner of machine learning. Please understand if my question is somehow basic. :)

I have a dataset of 25 features related to a rental house and I want to predict the price based on these features. Several questions occur to me:

1. I first regress price on all the other relevant features. Then, should I remove some features based on the results of Lasso regression or simple linear regression if the accuracy of prediction is my major goal? If so, how to select? I saw some coefficients of lasso regression show ".", should I remove these features?
2. How to decide regression metrics when comparing these four regression models? MAE, RMSE or Rsquared? Actually, my current result shows that there is no big difference between different models when comparing MAE, RMSE, Rsquared seperately. Simple linear regression even is the best according to these metrics.